# Selenium webdriver firefox how to get page in interactive readystate

Tags: c#, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I need to retrieve page and manipulate with this before the page will be fully loaded(document.readystate == "complete"), in case when document.readystate == "interactive", but dom elements already have loaded and become visible (in case, when all ajax requests are being loaded)

WebDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url); returns page only when all requests have processed

Comment: i try make something like that : `code` 
                    count = (int)(((IJavaScriptExecutor)_webDriver).
                    ExecuteScript(string.Format("return elements = document.getElementsByClassName('{0}').length", selector))); , but that js will run after full page loading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think this is default functionality of selenium that it waits till
>   document loading process completed. So if you are trying to run a code
>   after some page load event that code would always executed after
>   document loading process completed.

Answer (score 0):

You can set an Implicit wait or Use the something like PageToLoad
http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Timeouts.html